# State Association questions?

Tags: feature-request

We're discussing ways to handle questions from our members about the state chess association, and it occurred to me if we could have a tag for our association here, we could direct our members here, and would have a place for the question to be asked and for someone from the association to answer. I have no idea if that would fall within the purview of the site as it sits, so I figured I should ask.

We don't want to detract from anything you're trying to do here, so feel free to tell me the idea is all wet.